# How to make the wscript.exe popup stop showing up?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Using Windows 10

It has been months, maybe more than a year since this first showed up on my desktop

[image]

It seems like `wscript.exe` is trying to open something at `%USERDIR%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Update\startup.vbs`, but there is no such `Update` folder in my `AppData\Local` (I may have deleted it as there was no `startup.vbs` in the `Update` folder)

[image]

It is just very annoying, but closing the popup makes it appear again after a while, and letting it open doesn't seem to do any harm

But is there a way to avoid that popup at all?

- I have already tried checking my startup programs if `wscript.exe` was there, but it wasn't
- It may be tied to a service, but I can't see the `wscript.exe` PID in my active services list PID
- I am considering deleting `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe` but doing that may break something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
[autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to examine *all* startups. Run it as Administrator and filter for `wscript`.

Once you locate the `wscript` task, right-click it and select Delete.

If successful, you will see something like this
(photo found on internet) :

[image]

Comment: I did not have to get Autoruns, but from the picture you sent, I went into the Task Scheduler and found a task named `Update` that tried to launch that thing every 10 minutes, so now the problem is solved